# "Request is missing Host header" error in .Net Core Webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

The problem I experience is that the client app sends a HTTP 1.1 request without any "Host" header and the Asp.Net Core server app returns the following error: "Request is missing Host header."

I tried to add the missing header using filters/middleware but no luck - it's somewhere outside of pipeline one can reach by injecting code.

Is there a way to add the missing header? I guess due to HTTP 1.1 I can't omit the check?

The full exception I get is:

```
bad request data: ""Request is missing Host header.""
== APP == Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Request is missing Host header.
== APP ==    at void Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.EnsureHostHeaderExists()
== APP ==    at bool Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.TryParseRequest(ReadResult result, out bool endConnection)
== APP ==    at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests<TContext>(IHttpApplication<TContext> application)
== APP ==    at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequestsAsync<TContext>(IHttpApplication<TContext> application)
```

One point to note is that the endpoint is a SoapCore one.

Comment: How are you adding the Host header?  Please post your code.

Comment: With UseMiddleware<AddMissingHostMiddleware> or for filters     options.Filters.Add<AddMissingHostFilter>();

Comment: what is your client, a frontend app or mvc controller or any other httpclient ? and you have to add the header from the client.

Comment: it's some c++ app I have no access to. I was wondering if it's possible to inject the 'host' on the server. But the middleware runs AFTER the exception happens in the flow.